# Does Firefox disable plugins that failed to initialize?

Tags: linux, plugins, firefox-addon

I am trying to test a Mozilla plugin (developed using FireBreath) in the form of an `.so` shared object file. The plugin was developed on Ubuntu, where it works fine.

I am now trying it under OpenSUSE - so I first symlinked the `.so` file in `~/.mozilla/plugins`:

```
> ln -s /path/to/npXXX.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

... and then ran Firefox (7) from command line:

```
> /path/to/firefox -P myprofile
...
LoadPlugin: failed to initialize shared library libXext.so [libXext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
LoadPlugin: failed to initialize shared library /path/to/npXXX.so [/path/to/npXXX.so: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_get_mapped]
# and the LoadPlugin messages do NOT show a second time - probably because plugin is disabled (via about:addons).
```

And so I thought to try different stuff to look into this - but first, I restarted Firefox, and realized that on the second run I do *not* get the "*LoadPlugin: failed to initialize*" messages anymore! Then I tried removing the plugins symlink, and restarting FF; and adding it again, and restarting FF - still no error messages!

So, this tells me that probably Firefox somehow disabled/blacklisted the plugin (*but which one: libXext, npXXX or both?*) , but searching (grepping) for (np)XXX in '/path/to/myprofile/blocklist.xml' returns nothing (the plugin should use a email-like id, not those number GUIDs, so I'd expect that string to show in blocklist.xml if it's there).

Does anyone know: is the default behavior of Firefox to disable/blocklist plugins, that fail to load at first? If so, is there a way to force Firefox to load them again (and spit out error messages)? If you'd also have links to where this behavior is documented, it will be much appreciated :)

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Note: after I stopped seeing the error messages, I did the following:

- I am trying "`about:plugins`": "*No enabled plugins found*";
- then trying "`about:addons`", and clicking under Plugins: "*You don't have any add-ons of this type installed*";

This plugin is not embedded in an extension, so nothing new should be added in "`about:addons`" under "Extensions" - and as expected, nothing new shows there. Under Ubuntu (where all works), just by symlinking the plugin to `~/.mozilla/plugins`, the above two locations/screens start showing the plugin info.

This one of the things that puzzle me - if it just showed the plugin as "disabled", maybe I would have had a chance to re-enable it again (to get a new batch of error messages) - however, "`about:plugins`" and "`about:addons`" simply show nothing - so there's nothing I can use to enable from there. Which tells me Firefox has used a different method to disable the plugin(s) - but I cannot tell what it is...

Comment: You can check your Addins/extensions list via the manager (shift-ctrl-A in recent Firefoxes). Once an addin/extension is marked as disabled, FF will NOT try to load it again.

Comment: Try removing `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/pluginreg.dat`.

Comment: Cheers, @MarcB - I have edited the original post to clarify: after I stop seeing error messages, nothing shows related to this plugin in neither "`about:addons`" nor "`about:plugins`".

Comment: Many thanks @n.m. - that was it! It was the `pluginreg.dat` in my profile directory: `grep -i -B 1 XXX /path/to/myprofile/pluginreg.dat` returned "[INVALID]" - and after `mv`ing it to "`__pluginreg.dat`" and restarting Firefox from command line, I can see error messages again! Woot! :) Would you mind posting an answer so I can accept it? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has a cache for XPCOM modules ("fastload cache"), if a module fails to load Firefox won't try again. The cache is reset automatically if an extension is installed or if the application is updated. Starting with Firefox 4 you can also use `-purgecaches` command line flag to discard the cache.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Wladimir Palant - as far as I gather, FireBreath creates NPAPI plugins (which I guess means they are not XPCOM plugins) - still, great to know about `-purgecaches`... Cheers!